# Vector inequality proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$
I would appreciate if you could please let me know if my proof is correct or I should do some adjustments somewhere.

**Problem**: Let $B:=\{\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n:\Vert \vec{x}\Vert\leq 1\}$, $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b} \in B$, $\vec{c}$, $\vec{d}\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $\vert \vec{a}\cdot \vec{c}-\vec{b}\cdot \vec{d}\vert \leq \Vert \vec{b}-\vec{c}\Vert+\Vert \vec{a}-\vec{d}\Vert$.

> **Proof**:
>
> $\lvert \vec{a}\cdot \vec{c}-\vec{b}\cdot \vec{d}\rvert \leq \lvert \vec{a}\cdot \vec{c}+\vec{b}\cdot \vec{d}\rvert \leq \lvert\Vert\vec{a}\Vert\Vert\vec{c}\Vert+\Vert\vec{b}\Vert\Vert\vec{d}\Vert\rvert \leq \Vert\vec{a}\Vert\Vert\vec{c-b}\Vert+\Vert\vec{b}\Vert\Vert\vec{d-a}\Vert=\Vert\vec{a}\Vert\Vert\vec{b-c}\Vert+\Vert\vec{b}\Vert\Vert\vec{a-d}\Vert \leq \Vert\vec{b-c}\Vert+\Vert\vec{a-d}\Vert.$

Comment: The very first inequality is false. Set $a=b=d$ and $c=-a$ and you will find $2|a|^2\le 0$.

Comment: Thank you. Let me make an adjustment.

Comment: The same counterexample shows that the first inequality is still wrong.

Comment: You're right. But can you give a hint for this proof?

Comment: Start from $|a\cdot c -b\cdot d|$. Add & subtract the same quantity, rearrange, use the triangle inequality. Which quantity?

Comment: Thank you the hint. Here's what I did with it:
$|a\cdot c - b \cdot d|=|a\cdot c - b\cdot d + a\cdot b - a\cdot b|=|a\cdot (-b+c)+b\cdot (a-d)| \leq \Vert a \Vert \Vert c-b \Vert + \Vert b \Vert \Vert a-d \Vert \leq \Vert b-c \Vert + \Vert a -d \Vert$.

Comment: That's correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding & subtracting $a\cdot b$ in the quantity $|a\cdot c-b\cdot d|$, rearranging, then using the triangle inequality (see comments).